# Power BI | Collapse and expand lengthy values in one column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a column with lengthy values in my Power BI table. I would like it to only show a part of it so that the table isn't hard to navigate, and once the viewer clicks or do something, then it shows the whole value. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

There are posts about collapsing/expanding the whole column, as in keep it disappeared and then appear once you expand or vice versa, but I can't find a way to collapse/expand each values.

Following is an example. As you can see, "Bio" column is very lengthy, so I would it to show maybe a few lines in original view, and once the viewer wants to see the full Bio of that authors, then they can by a click or any action.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**OriginalTable**
[image: original table content]

**What I want**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with the truncated version, and a [Drill Through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough) to a report page for that single bio.